# How does tuple<Ts...>& base = t; work in tuple implementation

Tags: c++, c++11, templates, variadic-templates

When I read post [Variadic templates in C++](https://eli.thegreenplace.net/2014/variadic-templates-in-c/), I could not get one line in the implementation of tuple.

```
template <size_t k, class... Ts>
typename std::enable_if<
    k == 0, typename elem_type_holder<0, tuple<Ts...>>::type&>::type
get(tuple<Ts...>& t) {
  return t.tail;
}

template <size_t k, class T, class... Ts>
typename std::enable_if<
    k != 0, typename elem_type_holder<k, tuple<T, Ts...>>::type&>::type
get(tuple<T, Ts...>& t) {
  tuple<Ts...>& base = t;
  return get<k - 1>(base);
}
```

What does `tuple<Ts...>& base = t;` mean? I think type of t is `tuple<T, Ts...>&` which cannot be converted to `tuple<Ts...>&`.

Comment: Judging by the name of the variable, it's a derived-to-base conversion.

Comment: Looks like this implementation has tuples work something like `tuple<A, B, C> : tuple<B, C> { A tail; };`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is a conversion from a derived class reference to a base class reference which is a perfectly valid *C++* code.

As you might see in the implementation, `tuple<T, Ts...>` is derived from `tuple<Ts...>`:

```
template <class... Ts> struct tuple {};

template <class T, class... Ts>
struct tuple<T, Ts...> : tuple<Ts...> {
  tuple(T t, Ts... ts) : tuple<Ts...>(ts...), tail(t) {}

  T tail;
};
```

As `t` has a type of `tuple<T, Ts...>&`, you might cast it to `tuple<Ts...>&` and "throw out" one element from the tuple.